# Is there a way to test for console.log entires

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, browserstack

I'am currently trying to implement end to end unit testing for an App my team has. The app takes embedded video content on a website and records events that happen on the player.

Example: When our trackscript server is running we can go to https://www.thrillist.com/ and when a video is playing we can monitor the events that take place on the player such as mute, fastforward, pause, ect... and log them to the console.

We are trying to implement unit tests to check that the data being logged on these events is happening.

We are currently looking into BrowserStack to check cross browser compatibility and perhaps use a framework such as nightwatch.js for writing the unit tests.

My question is, can you write nightwatch tests that check for logs made to the console?

Comment: I'm confused - who is this app for? Is the idea that the end user wants to see something in *their* console (why?) or that you want to get information about those events sent somewhere else (what's the relevance of the logs?)

Comment: Why your app is printing this information to console ?

Comment: You could replace `console.log()` with your own function that informs the unit-testing framework.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's not recommended to unit test log messages: they are not part of the required behavior for a given piece of code, and should be able to change without breaking a bunch of tests.

However, if you really want to unit test log messages anyway, the recommended approach is the same as with anything you want to unit test: Wrap calls to the console messages in a separate class and use dependency injection to inject that class into your components. That way you can create spies, mocks, etc. for that dependency.